# Sending a two files at a time from an android phone to a python server

Tags: android, python, sockets

I have been trying to start writing code to send files in a directory on my android phone to a python server on computer. Is connection possible between a java socket client and python socket server. If please help with some reference code so that i could code on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Flask on the server side to implement webservices to communicate with the mobile. It is very easy to use. Here is the link for the library http://flask.pocoo.org/

Hope that helps